# how to do routing inside multiple instances of same component in angular 6

Tags: angular, routes, angular6, angular-routing, router-outlet

In my POC, I have two instances of dashboard displayed. I want the children to appear in the respective instance of the component.

But the current behaviour is, even if I click the button in the first instance, the children are getting rendered in the second instance itself.

Dashboard component.html

```
<div class="border">
  <p>
    dashboard works!
  </p>
  <button [routerLink]="['child1']">one</button>
  <button [routerLink]="['child2']">two</button>
  <div class="border m-1">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <p>-----------------------------------------------</p>
</div>
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="row">

  <app-dashboard></app-dashboard>    // instance 1

  <app-dashboard></app-dashboard>   //  instance 2

</div>
```

app.routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'child1',
  component: ChildOneComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'child2',
    component: ChildTwoComponent
  }
];
```

child-one.component.html

```
<p>
  child-one works!
</p>
```

child-two.component.html

```
<p>
  child-two works!
</p>
```

I want to write additional code in child 1 and child 2, once the components load.

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong or which approach to take? I have already tried using auxiliary routes and assigning id to the routes. But they didn't work.

I just want to create multiple instances of the same component and enable routing inside them so that the particular component that is routed is rendered inside the respective instance.

Answer (score 1):

Router is a global component so it doesn't bellong to one component.

if you have many instances, you need to use a function to reload one instance.

like :

`Dashboard component.html`

```
    <div class="border">
      <p>
        dashboard works!
      </p>
      <button (click)='routeone()'>one</button>
      <button (click)='routetwo()'>two</button>
        <div class="border m-1">
          {{mydata}}
       </div>
      <p>-----------------------------------------------</p>
    </div>
```

`Dashboard component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  mydata;
  constructor( private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  routeone(){
    this.mydata = 'childOne'
  }
  routetwo(){
    this.mydata = 'childTwo'
  }

}
```

Comment: Actually I need child1 and child2 to be components so that I can write additional code in them.

Comment: in this case include your child one and two component in you dashboard component, and then change the displayed component based on the url. i can show the implementation if you need it

Comment: Yes. Can you show me the implementation once. I am not getting where I did wrong. It is mandatory for me to use routing and not use ngSwitch.

Comment: **you can't use the routing** and choose witch instance of a component  you reload. in angular you can have just one instance of a router on the page. why do you need too have two dashboard on the same page ?